# Issue parsing web page data from twitter for dashing ruby app

Tags: ruby, dashing

I think my issue is the same as that in [Having problems with Ruby file from Dashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911114/having-problems-with-ruby-file-from-dashing) which as to date no answer.

Full problem is when I start dashing I get.

```
scheduler caught exception:
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
/home/bhladmin/Shopify-dashing-e672d84/dashboard/jobs/twitter_user.rb:19:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rufus-scheduler-2.0.23/lib/rufus/sc/jobs.rb:230:in `call'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rufus-scheduler-2.0.23/lib/rufus/sc/jobs.rb:230:in `trigger_block'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rufus-scheduler-2.0.23/lib/rufus/sc/jobs.rb:204:in `block in trigger'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rufus-scheduler-2.0.23/lib/rufus/sc/scheduler.rb:430:in `call'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rufus-scheduler-2.0.23/lib/rufus/sc/scheduler.rb:430:in `block in trigger_job'
```

Something isn't right on line 19, but I can't work out what...

The full section of code is below...

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'net/http'

# Track public available information of a twitter user like follower, follower
# and tweet count by scraping the user profile page.

# Config
# ------
twitter_username = ENV['TWITTER_USERNAME'] || 'foobugs'

SCHEDULER.every '2m', :first_in => 0 do |job|
  http = Net::HTTP.new("twitter.com", Net::HTTP.https_default_port())
  http.use_ssl = true
  response = http.request(Net::HTTP::Get.new("/#{twitter_username}"))
  if response.code != "200"
    puts "twitter communication error (status-code: #{response.code})\n#{response.body}"
  else

    tweets = /profile["']>[\n\t\s]*<strong>([\d.,]+)/.match(response.body)[1].delete('.,').to_i
    following = /following["']>[\n\t\s]*<strong>([\d.,]+)/.match(response.body)[1].delete('.,').to_i
    followers = /followers["']>[\n\t\s]*<strong>([\d.,]+)/.match(response.body)[1].delete('.,').to_i

    send_event('twitter_user_tweets', current: tweets)
    send_event('twitter_user_followers', current: followers)
    send_event('twitter_user_following', current: following)
  end
end
```

From the previous question it looks like the way of extracting the data from the webpage is the problem, but I don't know Ruby well enough. I've tried removing the ENV['TWITTER_USERNAME'] section to make sure the username I used (not the one above) is being used. If I dump out the raw html data then it contains the info I'm searching for so I know that part is working.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've solved this myself, by going about it a different way. I've changed the code to use the twitter API rather than page scraping. Details below... The auth checking and timeout isn't great so if anyone has hints on making that better they'd be welcome...

```
#### Get your twitter keys & secrets:
#### https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/tokens-devtwittercom
Twitter.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = 'YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY'
  config.consumer_secret = 'YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET'
  config.oauth_token = 'YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN'
  config.oauth_token_secret = 'YOUR_OAUTH_SECRET'

end

twitter_username = 'foobugs'

MAX_USER_ATTEMPTS = 10
user_attempts = 0

SCHEDULER.every '10m', :first_in => 0 do |job|
  begin
    tw_user = Twitter.user("#{twitter_username}")
    if tw_user
        tweets = tw_user.statuses_count
        followers = tw_user.followers_count
        following = tw_user.friends_count

        send_event('twitter_user_tweets', current: tweets)
        send_event('twitter_user_followers', current: followers)
        send_event('twitter_user_following', current: following)

    end
  rescue Twitter::Error => e
    user_attempts = user_attempts +1
    puts "Twitter error #{e}"
    puts "\e[33mFor the twitter_user widget to work, you need to put in your twitter API keys in the jobs/twitter_user.rb file.\e[0m"
    sleep 5
    retry if(user_attempts < MAX_USER_ATTEMPTS)
  end
end
```